# Proper way to Create a Swing Java Application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, constructor

I had some previous experience to swing applications at school, so I know how they work and will be fine designing them, but I am unsure of the best way to set my application up.

We only created smaller programs at school so we had almost all of our code in the constructor, but I want to create something larger, and am unsure of how I should set things up.

I have my base class with the constructor that will create my JFrame that I will use throughout the application, but what classes do I make to add my components, or use action listeners? I am unsure exactly of the proper way to do this, so a guiding step would be great.

Here is my class declaration/constructor:

```
public class SwingApp1 extends JFrame{

    public SwingApp1() {
        setTitle("Greens Tracker");
        setSize(800,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Now what do I put in my main, and in what manor should I be adding components?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's a broad question (and some what opinionated). As a general suggestion, you should avoid extending directly from top level containers, like `JFrame`, they couple your code to a single use case and reduce the possibility of re-use, besides, you're not really adding any new functionality to the class, besides, you constructor has a side effect (of making the window visible)

Comment: What @MadProgrammer said, and I'll also add, are you sure that you want to use a semi-deprecated library to create your GUI when other better supported GUI libraries (i.e., JavaFX) exist? Especially if library choice is not being dictated by academic requirements now.

Comment: As a general recommendation, I always like to start with a `JPanel`, it's easily customisable, can be added to what ever container I need (`JFrame`, `JDialog`, some other container) and build my UIs up from that.  You should also be making sure that you're starting your UIs in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread to avoid possible glitches and issues

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was just somewhat familiar with Swing, so I thought it might be easier to start there. This JavaFX, is it much different / better?

Comment: I can't speak for better, since I don't know it well (@MadProgrammer can answer this though), but the main thing that it has going for it is that it is ***supported***. Whichever you choose, strive to separate your logic from your view a la MVC (model-view-controller), so that if you want to change GUI libraries later, you'll have a much easier time doing so.

Comment: @nicetoCyou It's neither better or worse, it's just a different API - Many people tout it as the replacement for Swing, but I'm not fan due to the lack of native UI look and feel support out of the box (users are so hard to please). It was intended as a Flash competitor, but now the industry is moving away from these type of plugins, they've needed to find a new use for it. Let's face, version 1 didn't even have a `JTable` equivalent. Most UI development is either Web or focused on single/limited platforms, so cross platform development has slowed (or moved to the mobile space)

Comment: @nicetoCyou One thing I would give JavaFX a thumbs up to, is it's inbuilt animation support from the start, but that's just a feature I like ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"main thing that it has going for it is that it is **supported**."* I guess the supported to mean that Oracle offers more support for maintaining & expanding the API. OTOH I'd point out that I won't believe that Oracle is committed to supporting it until it makes it into the main Java docs and Java Tutorial. They have in the past touted APIs that they then (often quietly) dropped all support for. There is also that there are probably more people on SO experienced with Swing, and greater number of existing questions (Swing 69K vs Java-FX 23K) from which to search answers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: and yet, and yet. We may not know how well supported JavaFX will be, but we ***do*** know how well supported Swing will be -- nil, zilch, and nada. And surely as code, platforms and OS's evolve, this will lead to breaking of code.

Answer (score 1):

Good way of setting up your JFrame is

```
public GUI() {
    buildGUI();
}

private void buildGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(500, 300);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The program starts at the main as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SwingApp1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

which can be abbreviated since Java 8 as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SwingApp1().setVisible(true));
}
```

The JFrame constructor could be as follows. A setVisible I leave to the call,
and `pack()` will layout the contents.

```
public SwingApp1() {
    setTitle("Greens Tracker");
    setSize(800,500);
    ... add components, maybe in a separate method.
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Actually look into MVC, Model View Controller.

I generally maky an XyzApplication class as *controller*, the JFrame being the main *view* and the separately kept data (in the application) the *model*.

It should be mentioned, that JavaFX may be slightly more advisable, say without FXML layout files. A bit more learning involved, but nicer behavior.

Other advise would be to use a build infrastructure like **maven**. That helps with libraries ("dependencies") and provides "best practices" like build directories (src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/resources ...).

Of course a version control system like git or mercurial.